# Discord.js SQLITE_ERROR: table scores has no column named points

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have the following error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: table scores has no column named points
```

Does anyone know a fix?

I also am also using discord.js commando, so my user is defined in the run...

Code:

```js
run(msg, {user, reason}) {
        msg.delete()
        if(!user) {msg.say(`**Cannot find user! Make sure it's a valid member of this server!**`)
     } else {
            msg.say(`**${user.tag} has been warned for ${reason}!**`)   
            sqlite.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId = "${user.id}"`).then(row =>{
                    if (!row) {
                        sqlite.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, points) VALUES (?,?)", [user.id, 1])
                    } else {
                        sqlite.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points  + 1} WHERE userId = ${user.id}`)
                    }
                }).catch(()=>{
                   sqlite.run(`CREATE TABLE OF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, points INTEGER)`).then(()=> {
                     sqlite.run(`INSERT INTO scores (userId, points) VALUES (?, ?)`, [user.id, 1])
                })
            })
            
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain the promises to catch them that way.

```
sqlite.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId = "${user.id}"`).then(row =>{
  if (!row) {
      return sqlite.run("INSERT INTO scores (userId, points) VALUES (?,?)", [user.id, 1])
  } else {
      return sqlite.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points  + 1} WHERE userId = ${user.id}`)
  }
}).catch(()=>{
 return sqlite.run(`CREATE TABLE OF NOT EXISTS scores (userId TEXT, points INTEGER)`).then(()=> {
    return sqlite.run(`INSERT INTO scores (userId, points) VALUES (?, ?)`, [user.id, 1])
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I did that and it still has the same error, but yea i probably should get in the habit of that...

Comment: add returns inside the catch, and add a second catch after that.  I'm pretty sure either `CREATE TABLE` or the insert after it is throwing because sqlite has a scores table already.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, see i knew i was a nub. Thanks again :)